# trying to prove a property of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I want to prove this property:

> If $V$ is a vector space, $X$ a vector in $V$, then $0\odot X = 0$.

My proof:

From axiom $1\odot X = X$,
\begin{align}
1 &\odot X = X \\
&\implies& (1+0) \odot X &= X \\
&\implies& 1 \odot X \oplus 0 \odot X &= X 
&&\text{(from axioms of the vector space)} \\
&\implies& X \oplus 0 \odot X &= X \\
&\implies& -X \oplus X \oplus0 \odot X &= X \oplus -X \\
&\implies& (-X \oplus X) \oplus 0 \odot X &= X \oplus -X 
&&\text{(associative property)} \\
&\implies& 0 \oplus 0 \odot X &= 0 \\
&\implies& 0 \odot X &= 0
\end{align}
Done.

Is my proof ok? Or there is another simple way?

Comment: Other than the use of unusual notation, this is the standard proof that $0 \cdot x = 0$, whether in a vector space, a more general module, or a ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this...
$$
0 \odot x = (0+0)\odot X = (0\odot x)\oplus(0\odot x)
$$
add $-(0\odot x)$ to both sides
$$
(0 \odot x) -(0\odot x)= \big((0\odot x)\oplus(0\odot x)\big)-(0\odot x)
\\
O = (0\odot x)\oplus\big((0\odot x)-(0\odot x)\big) = (0\odot x) \oplus O = (0\odot x).
$$
Note: I wrote $0$ for the zero scalar and $O$ for the zero vector;  I wrote $+$ for addition of scalars and $\oplus$ for addition of vectors.

---

I did not have to use the axom $1\odot x = x$.